# Best way to include specific jQuery selectors for different pages

Tags: jquery, performance

Here's an issue that we have regularly.  Consider this bit of jQuery:

```
$(".tabs").remove();
```

The above is fine, however, it's a shame to do this if out of 100 individual pages only 1 page features elements with the "tabs" class.

Our solution so far has been to do this:

```
if ($("body#library").length > 0) {
    $(".tabs").remove();
    // More Library page specific code here
} else if ($("body#links").length > 0) {
    // Links page specific code here
}
```

Then on the required page we'd do this:

```
<body id="library">
```

My thinking is that finding `$("body#library")` will be fast for jQuery.  We can then give each page an ID, and using a single JavaScript file we can include page specific code for each one.

My concern is that this still isn't very efficient.  Another idea is to have a specific JavaScript file for each page.  However this will increase HTTP requests.  I often see websites with 10 or more included JavaScript files per page and in my opinion that's too heavy.  We'd prefer a single site-wide JavaScript file as it's easier to manage and means a single file only needs to be requested (and cached) once.

Are there any other ideas of how to handle this?

Comment: I suppose you could have seperate on-load functions for different pages (defined all in the one js file) then put a document ready which calls the appropriate function inline in the page (depending on which page).  But really, I think your existing solution should be fine performance wise (at least with respect to this factor - I haven't seen the rest of the code of course!)

Comment: You don't need extra js files. Just put such short site-specific snippets in inline scripts!

Comment: The above example is just basic, there could be lots of page specific code within the IF blocks - too much to go inline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it depends on how likely it is for a user to open several different pages.

If the user will likely only load the library **or** the links page I would use one global javascript file included in all pages and a second one on each page with only the code required for the specific page.

However if the user will likely open many/most of the pages I'd put it in one big file and somehow determine which code needs to run (for example with an ID on the body).

Also, if you remove the tag name from the selector it will be faster since it could use the native `getElementById()` function directly. (`$('#library')` instead of `$('body#library')`).

See this [performance test](http://jsperf.com/id-selector-with-tag) I set up.